# Tap label in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a label I want to tap on using `addGestureRecognizer`. I put it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but when I do `print(label.text)`, it prints a label from another cell. But when I put it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, it prints out the right label for that cell.

What is the best way to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
var variableToPass: String!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell : MainCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainCell

        variableToPass = label1.text

        cell.label1.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapLabel = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapLabel(_:)))
        cell.label1.addGestureRecognizer(tapLabel)



        return cell as MainCell
    }

func tapCommentPost(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(variableToPass)
    }
```

Comment: can you show the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code and gesture code

Comment: use custom UITableViewCell class for tableview implementation.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik just edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to set the `tap.tag = indexPath.row` for identify which cell you tabbed for Find, for example

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell : MainCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainCell

        variableToPass = label1.text

        cell.label1.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapLabel = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapLabel(_:)))
        cell.label1.tag = indexPath.row
        tapLabel.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell.label1.addGestureRecognizer(tapLabel)



        return cell as MainCell
    }

func tapLabel(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let searchlbl:UILabel = (sender.view as! UILabel)
    variableToPass =  searchlbl.text!
    print(variableToPass)
    }
```

Comment: can you please change answer according to my edited question above?

Comment: @johnniexo88 - ya sure

Comment: I get "value of type uitapgesturerecognizer has no member tag"

Comment: not resolved. your code "tapLabel.tag = indexPath.row", I get `value of type uitapgesturerecognizer has no member tag`

Comment: @johnniexo88 - sorry my bro I only made the mistake , now check the answer , I added this line `cell.label1.tag = indexPath.row`

Comment: @johnniexo88 - Sorry bro , I took for this for two days, sorry I am not seen clearly,

Comment: its okay man! i have another problem now... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924688/tap-button-in-tableview-wrong-cell

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your current code: (1) You're setting `variableToPass` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so assuming label1.text is the label belonging to the cell, as the table loads, the `variableToPass` will always contain the label text of the last loaded cell. (2) `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` can be called multiple times for each cell (for example, as you scroll) so you could be adding multiple gesture recognizers to a single cell.

In order to resolve issue #1, remove the `variableToPass` variable entirely and instead directly access the gesture's label view. In order to resolve issue #2, I'd recommend adding the gesture recognizer to your custom `MainCell` table view cell, but if you don't want to do that, at least only add a gesture recognizer if one isn't already there.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainCell

    if cell.label1.gestureRecognizers?.count == 0 { 
        cell.label1.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let tapLabel = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapCommentPost(_:))) // I assume "tapLabel" was a typo in your original post
        cell.label1.addGestureRecognizer(tapLabel)
    }

    return cell
}

func tapCommentPost(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print((sender.view as! UILabel).text) // <-- Most important change!
}
```