# Tap button in tableview - wrong cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

Hi I am trying to pass a variable in the cell which is the label when i click on a button in the cell. but the problem is every when I put the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it gets the label from the wrong cell every time. why and how to fix this?

```
var variableToPass: String!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : MainCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainCell") as! MainCell

    variableToPass = label1.text

    cell.label1.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapLabel(_:)))
    cell.label1.addGestureRecognizer(tapButton)

    return cell as MainCell
}

func tapButton(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifierName", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueIdentifierName" {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        viewController.getVariablePassed = variableToPass
    }
}
```

Comment: You should separate out your code and subclass the UITableViewCell and then in that sub class create the tap gesture recognizer. Also, you need to set the delegate of the gesture recognizer to the CELL.

Comment: You can use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method for that.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni you can, I do this all the time, but never like this, always in a subclass of UITableViewCell, never in the in controller

Comment: yes that way you can do it. @Loxx

Comment: if you go this route, attach a block to the Cell with a property exposed, the block then can be set to the "tapButton" function by setting the block to weakified self and weakified cell, this is complicated, so I won't confuse you if this is too much, point being, it's possible, but don't do it the way you're trying to do it

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is set up, `variableToPass` is always the text in the last cell acquired from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Instead, set `variableToPass` in your `tapButton` method, because then you know what cell was selected and you can correctly set `variableToPass`:

```
func tapButton(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let label = sender.view as! UILabel
    self.variableToPass = label.text
    performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifierName", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My way to do this is using a cell delegate and registering my viewController as delegate for the cell, later when the user taps on the UIButton I will call a method like

`- (void)buttonWasPressedWithIndexPath:(NSIndexpath*)indexPath`

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath I pass the indexPath as a cell property